# Векторы с++. Создание двумерного вектора

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть Вектор 1, для обозначения времени суток. В нем находятся 24 нуля. Так же имеются работы, выполняемые разное время. 3 Вектор описывает прибыль, которую мы получим от выполнения работы. Мне нужно объединить как-то вторые два вектора, для того, чтобы с помощью жадного алгоритма определить максимальную возможность заработка. Так как объединить два вектора?

Comment: `firstVector.insert(firstVector.end(), secondVector.begin(), secondVector.end());`?

Comment: Мне не нужно их объединить, нужно чтоб характеристикой первого элемента была его стоимость. Как в  двумерном массиве

Comment: То есть вы хотите получить вектор пар? `vector<pair<int, int>> result; for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) result.emplace_back(firstVector[i], secondVector[i]);`

Comment: Да, все так, спасибо

Comment: да не за что :)